# How to convert multi nested object into multidimensional array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Current format:**

```
{
  "SD": {
    "Key": "SD",
    "City": "San Diego",
    "Name": "Padres"
  },
  "WSH": {
    "Key": "WSH",
    "City": "Washington",
    "Name": "Nationals"
  }
}
```

**Expected format:**

```
[
  {
    "Key": "SD",
    "City": "San Diego",
    "Name": "Padres"
  },
  {
    "Key": "WSH",
    "City": "Washington",
    "Name": "Nationals"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `Object.values(...)` which makes an array out of all the values from your object:

```js
const obj = {
  "SD": {
    "Key": "SD",
    "City": "San Diego",
    "Name": "Padres"
  },
  "WSH": {
    "Key": "WSH",
    "City": "Washington",
    "Name": "Nationals"
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like ***Object.values*** is the answer, you can use it like this.

```
Object.values(your_object)
```

And it will return your expected format, here is the documentation on how it works if you would like to read further.
[Object.values Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)